# If OP accepts a suggested edit, take it out of the review queue and auto-accept it

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

A non-participating user did a drive-by edit of an answer, changing the answer. It was in my review queue and I rejected it. However, 3 other users with high accept-reject rates accepted it. I rolled back the edit because it was invalid, and commented on the answer accordingly.

As it turns out, the OP of the answer accepted the change. That was not apparent to me.

Either

- it needs to be more obvious that this drive-by change (which should be rejected) was accepted by the OP, or
- if the OP accepts an edit, it should be removed from the Suggested Edit queue and be auto-accepted, or
- changes accepted by OP should look like OP edited the question themselves, or something.

Comment: It already is auto-accepted when the OP accepts.

Comment: I couldn't find documentation stating such.

Comment: Hopefully someone will post a link as I'm not sure where it is documented, but that is how the system acts.  In the review queue, the OP's name has a different background color, just as yours does in the comments of this question.

Comment: Also, mind posting a link to the edit?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2303945

Comment: The OP was the *last* vote on that review. 17 seconds after your vote.

Answer (score 1):

From the [FAQ about suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work):

> - The owner of a post may cast a binding vote to accept or reject any modification to their post.

This behavior is documented; additionally, in the edit review, the OP's name appears slightly shaded as it typically does. As such, your feature request is [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed); when the OP accepts the edit, the edit is removed from the queue.

Changing the edit to the OP's ownership would remove responsibility for the edit from the suggesting user.

While yes, in this case, the reviewers should have rejected the edit, the OP has better authority to judge the usefulness of the edit. The OP can accept any edit they so choose (as long as it's not actively harmful).

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time. I just feel that this whole thing could have been avoided if the user who "approved 117 edit suggestions and rejected 7 edit suggestions" paid more attention.

Comment: @Joe No worries, it happens. We all wish people would stop robo-reviewing, but we have yet to think of a sound way of doing this.